# how to set setjavascriptenabled in android webview using kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-webview

I am new in `Kotlin`, and while working on a `WebView` app. I found

1. `val webSettings = mWebView.settings
   webSettings.javaScriptEnabled = true`

2.`mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true)`

1 and 2 are Kotlin statements

What is the difference between these? which one is better to use?

There is no detail explanation about these.

Comment: There is nothing difference between them  both are used to Enabled `JavaScript` in `WebView`

Comment: I got confused...

Comment: that's what a thynthetic property is. `webSettings.javaScriptEnabled = true` is performing same code as `mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true)`. `mWebView.settings` as well as `webSettings.javaScriptEnabled` are both synthetic properties generated by Kotlin from `getSettings().` and `setJavaScriptEnabled` methods

Answer (score 4):

There is no difference between both.

**Kotlin** supports **property access syntax**, which means if you have declared one variable in Kotlin, it'll have it's `getters & setters` by default *(No need to declare explicitly)*.

You can also access `getters & setters` by accessing variable directly,

So, acessing **setter method** in kotlin :

```
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true)
```

be like this if using **property access syntax**,

```
webSettings.javaScriptEnabled = true
```

More from [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html)

> **Conclusion:**
>
> Simply,
>
> if you assign variable in kotlin -> it will treated as **`setter`**
>   for that (in your case)
>
> if you access variable in kotlin -> it will treated as **`getter`**
>   for that

Comment: so in kotlin, there is no setJavascriptEnabled() fun and javascriptEnabled variable used to set javascript. am I right?

Comment: No. Kotlin does provide `setJavascriptEnabled()` method, but it's treated as setter for setting `javaScriptEnabled` variable, so it can be accessed directly like your 1st point for setting variable. You're free to use both.

Comment: It can be accessed directly unless you're having custom getters & setters.

Comment: I am too weak in english. sorry for that... I almost got your point.

Comment: No issues, feel free to ask anything, it's stack**overflow**.. we're all here to help.

Comment: one correction bro. mwebview.getsettings().setJavascriptEnabled(true) in kotlin. not in java, there is no semicolon

Comment: @c49 please check updated answer *(You can edit someone's answer too)*.

Comment: yes, this is what I am looking for. So I can use both of them, Not a problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First it will not different between writing a statement in android with java or kotlin .. both will make the same effect.
For using webSetting there is no different between both .. 
but most of tutorials use the first one to get the Websetting object one then modify at as they want to enable or disable any webview setting instead of calling getSetting object every time they need it.
You can read more about Webiew in android from this article.

https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/building-hybrid-android/9781449361907/ch04.html

Comment: there is no semicolon at last bro. that's too kotlin